# Magento 1.9.1 php-fpm High CPU Usage but Low Memory Usage

Tags: php, performance, magento

I am running 2 pretty standard Magento websites in a cloud with 16 vCPU and 16 vRAM. But today I found out that my sites are running horribly slow with almost 100% vCPU all the time, but only 10% RAM. I can't figure out what the problem is and no idea where to check first.

This is my top command:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
22778 k6719876  20   0  307m  38m 4516 R  3.0  0.2   0:06.77 php-fpm
20862 enji      20   0  121m  61m 4148 R  2.7  0.4   0:13.05 lmtp
22785 k6719876  20   0  381m  48m 6192 R  2.7  0.3   0:05.99 php-fpm
22937 k6719876  20   0  314m  45m 4500 R  2.7  0.3   0:04.62 php-fpm
23872 enji      20   0  116m  59m 3992 R  2.7  0.4   0:00.61 lmtp
 1471 mysql     20   0 2475m 221m 8572 S  2.3  1.4   1:42.89 mysqld
22777 k6719876  20   0  313m  44m 4500 R  2.3  0.3   0:05.37 php-fpm
22792 k6719876  20   0  320m  51m 4512 R  2.3  0.3   0:06.83 php-fpm
22809 k6719876  20   0  315m  46m 4572 R  2.0  0.3   0:06.73 php-fpm
23447 enji      20   0  402m  32m 6140 R  2.0  0.2   0:02.40 php-fpm
24095 enji      20   0  332m  30m 4392 S  2.0  0.2   0:00.31 php-fpm
24017 enji      20   0  324m  24m 4276 S  1.7  0.1   0:00.56 php-fpm
23971 root      20   0  139m 4648 1256 S  0.3  0.0   0:00.01 cpanel_php_fpm
23981 root      20   0 13180 1184  864 R  0.3  0.0   0:00.08 top
    1 root      20   0 19284 1496 1292 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.12 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd/967975
```

PHP-FPM often peak to 10% CPU each

Comment: Did you setup the sites your self, can you check with `htop` which processes consume most of the CPU? Is the database running on the same host?

Comment: @ghovat hi, yes i did setup myself and the DB is in the same host (DB size around 400MB).

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size, # cores of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From SSH root login, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Hi @WilsonHauck I have posted on pastebin, here is the link https://pastebin.com/8EwK1WLB. Thank you